# Ruby/SDL vs. RUDL

Tags: sdl, ruby

I'm interested in using Ruby for 2D games. I have to pick between Ruby/SDL and RUDL, both of which are Ruby SDL wrappers.

Which is better? Better means "less bugs" and "more usable," although the latter is a matter of taste.

I notice that Ruby/SDL was last updated in 2012 (according to SourceForge), and RUDL in 2010; other than that, I don't know much about either.

Please share your experiences, good and bad.

Comment: Kind of "[Which technology to use](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/)?" isn't it?

Comment: Kind of. I see it more as "which of these two (seemingly dead) libraries do I use?"

Comment: Same thing, defined as one of the types of questions that are not a good fit for the site in the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq). It's a good question for chat though.

Comment: Okay. Your objection (and close vote) is noted. :)